# Configure the ScriptsEditor Autosave location in DBeaver on Mac

Tags: dbeaver

**DBeaver** on Mac has and feature
where all the ScriptEditors are autosave and the content in Editors are available between the restart of tool.

I'm unable to find the setting to customize the location where these Editor scripts are saved.

**Reason why I need it, information not directly related to above problem**

I do development between couple of machines, wanted to autosave these scripts on network drive so I can access them from all machines.